# How to exclude Express view engines from Webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, webpack, bundling-and-minification

I'm bundling my CLI app using Webpack v4. One of the dependencies is Express, and this causes a warning:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/express/lib/view.js 81:13-25
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/application.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/lib/express.js
 @ ./node_modules/express/index.js
```

That comes from [this line](https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/80f1ea9/lib/view.js#L81) within Express:

```
/**
 * Initialize a new `View` with the given `name`.
 *
 * Options:
 *
 *   - `defaultEngine` the default template engine name
 *   - `engines` template engine require() cache
 *   - `root` root path for view lookup
 *
 * @param {string} name
 * @param {object} options
 * @public
 */

function View(name, options) {
  var opts = options || {};

  this.defaultEngine = opts.defaultEngine;
  this.ext = extname(name);

  // ...

  if (!opts.engines[this.ext]) {
    // load engine
    var mod = this.ext.substr(1)
    debug('require "%s"', mod)

    // default engine export
    var fn = require(mod).__express // <-- this require is the problem
```

There's quite a few questions asking about how to fix this by [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44703030/how-to-fix-express-warning-webpack) [bundling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31102035/how-can-i-use-webpack-with-express) [express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692643/webpack-and-express-critical-dependencies-warning) at all, or not bundling anything from node_modules.

For me that would defeat the point (I'm trying to shrink my deployed file footprint), so I want to fix this whilst keeping express inside my bundle. In my case I don't use view engines at all, and this require exists solely to load view engines on demand, so I really just want the warning to go away.

If I'm confident that this require will never be called, how can I tell webpack to ignore it completely?

Comment: Most of express features over the years have been extracted out of express, eg. `express.static` etc, so if you don't require the template feature you could maybe bypass and not use express.  Possibly the main reason your using express is for the routing logic, so this module might be handy -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/router

Comment: I'm not actually even using express directly, it's used through another dependency. Really though I'm just looking for a webpack config fix, I don't want to rewrite my whole app to avoid a webpack warning :-)

Comment: Oh, I might have an idea, I'll post an answer as it's not ideal for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

What you could maybe try is alter you webpack config module rules so that 
`view` unit uses the `null-loader`

This will of course make `View` return `null` but if you never touch views it might be ok.

example.

```
rules: [
 {
   test: require.resolve("express/view"),
   use: 'null-loader',
  },
],
```

Looking at `application`

`this.set('view', View);`  hopefully View been null here doesn't cause issues.

The only other place `View` is then mentioned in application is then in `render` that you say your not using.  So fingers crossed this won't cause any side effects.