# Bundling expressjs with esbuild gives missing view.js warning

Tags: node.js, express, bundle, esbuild

I'm trying to bundle an "express.js" script with esbuild using

```
esbuild index.js --bundle --platform=node --outfile=server.js
```

to run as a netlify/aws lambda function and seem always to get this warning:

```
> node_modules/express/lib/view.js: warning: This call to "require" will not be bundled because the argument is not a string literal
    81 │     var fn = require(mod).__express
       ╵              ~~~~~~~
```

The function seems to run but I would like to find out what could be wrong and I couldn't find any hints online anywhere?

Answer (score 3):

The bundling process tries to produce a single file containing all of your code, but the warning is telling you that express contains some code that cannot be bundled into a single file. I'm not familiar with express but apparently this is also a problem with express and Webpack (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44703030/875930) for an example).

Assuming you still keep the `node_modules/express` folder around next to your bundle when you run the code, you could solve this problem with esbuild the same way [the Webpack solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45206799/875930) works: by marking the `express` package as external. That would look like this:

```
esbuild index.js --bundle --platform=node --outfile=server.js --external:express
```